# C# .Net Connectivity with M.S Access Database not inserting

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, database-connection

**App.config**

```
add name="con" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\transport_db.accdb  ; Persist Security Info=True"/>
```

**Connection object**

```
con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
```

when i inserting data no error generating but when i look my original database there is no entry with any data. but when i check inside bin/debug folder and open that database record will show there.

**With Full path connection string**

```
add name="con" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=**c:\c#\MyApp\transport_db.accdb**  ; Persist Security Info=True"/>
```

if i use that full path connection string then data are inserted into my original database which i connected to my application.

I am finding solution for **dynamic** connection string cause after creating setup file database path will find automatically change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [C# DataBase Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: @Plutonix i saw that artical but i dont resolve that my problem.